# COUNTIF OR Criteria fails when first Criteria is not met, why?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to understand why my countif formula is not working and I wanted to see if there was a way around it.

`=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$F:$F,2,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,{"*2023 April*","*2023 May*","*2023 June*"})`

The column it is looking at is Column D of Sheet1 for these dates. The column does not have a value with "2023 April" in it so it just returns 0 even though I have values with "2023 May" and "2023 June".

If I change the formula to the following it works:

`=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$F:$F,2,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,{"*2023 May*","*2023 June*","*2023 April*"})`

So, as long as the first criteria is met it works.. if the first criteria is not found then it will just return a 0 for the count.

Why? Can this be fixed via formula or do I have to just rearrange it like I did? This seems weird.

Comment: Use `QUERY()` and `matches` operator to count using `OR` logic.

Comment: Is there no way to do it with countifs? I'm not against using query but I want to understand why it's not working and if there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array formula which is not array enabled.

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$F:$F,2,'Sheet1'!$D:$D,{"*2023 April*","*2023 May*","*2023 June*"}))
```

Comment: This works but it places 3 values in 3 cells. One for each month. I need the sum of those values.

Comment: I wrapped it in a SUM formula and it worked. Is that acceptable? If so, update your answer and I will mark this as my choice. Thanks!

Comment: You can use SUM. But instead of ArrayFormula(SUM()) we can use SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Are there any performance differences between SUM, SUMPRODUCT and using what I had before without the array? (assuming I only enter months that have values?)

Comment: In this scenario ArrayFormula(sum()) and sumproduct() are the same. What you had before is an array formula, which is a formula that performs array operations, that wasn't array enabled, so it only evaluated the first value in criterion.